# Finding the sum of a geometric progression with common ratio $\dfrac1e$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Here is the question:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n}$$

Instead of using the formula of $\large\frac{1}{1-r}$ I want to try to get the partial sums.

$S_1 = e^{-1}$

$S_2 = e^{-1} + e^{-2} = \frac{e + 1}{e^2}$

$S_3 = e^{-1} + e^{-2} + e^{-3} = \frac{e^2 + e + 1}{e^3}$

$S_4 = e^{-1} + e^{-2} + e^{-3} + e^{-4} = \frac{e^3 + e^2 + e + 1}{e^4}$

How can we get $S_n$ for this?

What I see:

$$\displaystyle S_n = \frac{\displaystyle 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} e^k }{e^{n}}$$
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^n = T$$

But the series in the numerator is divergent since $|r| = |e| = e > 1$

Comment: What do you mean by $\displaystyle S_n = \frac{\displaystyle (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^n) + 1}{e^{n}}$ ? Where does that $\infty$ come from ? In addition to that the indexes are messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_n=\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{e^2}+\frac{1}{e^3}+\cdots\frac{1}{e^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{e^n}$$
$$\frac{S_n}{e}=\frac{1}{e^2}+\frac{1}{e^3}+\cdots\frac{1}{e^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{e^n}+\frac{1}{e^{n+1}}$$

$$\frac{S_n}{e}-S_n=S_n\left(\frac{1}{e}-1\right)=\frac{1}{e^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{e}$$

$$\Rightarrow S_n = \frac{ e^{-(n+1)}-e^{-1} }{e^{-1}-1}$$

Also notice that $$\lim_{n \to \infty }S_n=\frac{1}{e-1}$$

Comment: So, when he says "instead of using the formula $\frac{1}{1-r}$", it will be OK repeat the usual proof of that formula?

Comment: @DigitalBrain, thank you for the reply. This is great, but can we perhaps use integrals in finding the sum? ? Thanks!

Comment: @Amad 27
$$\frac{1}{e-1}\approx 0.5819$$
 $$\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=\frac{1}{e}\approx0.3678$$

Comment: Hello: Could this be something? I would appreciate a comment on this method:


$= \displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^{m} ne^{-n} $

$= \displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} me^{-m} \text{dm}$

But that does not work, since the output won't present an $m$ term. 

Advice please? Thanks!

Comment: @DigitalBrain, exactly, I looked at that and I was thinking if there is a way to evaluate this whole sum using that method ..

Comment: You'll need to have something similar to $\frac{1}{n}$, Like you had in your question which will be replaced by $dx$ of your integral

Answer (score 1):

What you see is only $$\displaystyle S_n = \frac{\displaystyle 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} e^k }{e^{n}}$$

Comment: Thanks for that, that is what I meant, but how can you evaluate that sum? thanks!

Comment: Digital Brain gave it !

Comment: Hello: Could this be something? I would appreciate a comment on this method:


$= \displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n=1}^{m} ne^{-n} $

$= \displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} me^{-m} \text{dm}$

But that does not work, since the output won't present an $m$ term. 

Advice please? Thanks!